# ensure a snap package is the latest version

Tags: snap

I need to check if a snap package is installed and install the latest version.
Or if it is installed, refresh to the latest version

In other words, I want the latest version one way or another.

For example, I'm using this:

```
if snap list libreoffice; then
  sudo snap refresh libreoffice
else
  sudo snap install libreoffice
fi
```

Is there a shorter, better method to use?

```
sudo snap <magic> libreoffice
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if different channels offer different versions; `snap refresh` or a simple `snap install` will not change or select a specific channel (such as beta/edge).  I see two options with `snap list libreoffice` (310, 311) but you've not specified if you're wanting the *latest* including from *edge* or *beta* channels.

Comment: I want a one command that either installs or refreshes the snap package automatically.

Comment: Snaps update automatically, so I don't really understand why you need this. Can you explain why you need a script like this?

Comment: okay. Why does snap have a "refresh" command?

Comment: The `refresh` command allows us to check & kick off upgrades when we choose.. giving us *extra* control that just the system upgrading when its cron jobs etc are run.